# What is the best way to Dockerize a Play2-Scala application?

Tags: scala, docker, java-8, playframework

For the first case, I followed a blog post and it's recommended adding **Java** and **Docker** plugins in the ***build.sbt*** file like:

```
enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)

dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:8"
dockerEntrypoint := Seq("bin/test", "-Denv=dev")
```

however, it seems to build an unstable image, the container fails to start with an error:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/docker/RUNNING_PID
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.createPidFile(ProdServerStart.scala:148)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:46)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:30)
    at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

Can someone help me out on this or on using a Dockerfile instead.

Comment: try giving a look here: https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out using Dockerfile; I wrote a Dockerfile in the root directory, the use `docker build` command

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

#Add build artifacts into stage dir
ADD target/universal/stage stage

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["stage/bin/play2_app", "-Dplay.http.secret.key=abcdef12345"]
```

Then build the image:

```
$ docker build -t play2-test-app:v1 .
```

Run the docker image locally

```
$ docker run -d --name play2-test-container -p 9000:9000 [images id]
```

First ensure the container is running by listing all running containers:

```
$ docker ps
```

> View your app on browser at:

```
localhost:9000
```